# get the column value in sql server in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The following is my query and I need to column value in select subquery instead i get column name 
@Temp = temporary table

```
insert into @Temp([dateTime],Reading) 
values (@startDate,(select top(1) @trendId from TABLENAME where deviceTimestamp >= @startDate and deviceTimestamp < @tempdt  order by deviceTimestamp desc))

ALTER PROCEDURE ProcName 
#trendId as nvarchar(max), 
#startDate as datetime, 
#endDate as datetime 
AS 
BEGIN 
  declare #stt varchar(200) = 'select deviceTimestamp,' + #trendId + ' '+'as reading 
  from TableName 
  where deviceTimestamp >= '+#startDate+'and deviceTimestamp < '+#endDate+' 
  order by deviceTimestamp desc' 

exec(#stt)END
```

I get the error :

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.)

Comment: as i know you can't send column name with a parameter in TSQL. you will need Dynamic queries.

Comment: Please suggest something so that i get value not column name in select subquery

Comment: you have to send column name as parameter ?

Comment: Yes I want to pass as parameter

Comment: Not clear to me! Can you?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale where #trendId is parameter of my procedure which i pass in insert subquery

Comment: please share the non-dynamic query and what is datatype for `deviceTimestamp`? will transform into dynamic!

Comment: @ Halil İbrahim  I need the #trendId column value in select query instead I get column name what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @columnList varchar(75)
DECLARE @city varchar(75)

SET @columnList = 'AddressID, AddressLine1, City'
SET @city = '''London'''
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM Person.Address WHERE City = ' + @city

EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

[Check this link out.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) Dynamic SQL seems like what you need you can pass tablename,table columns dynamicly to your Query. so with this you will be able to pass column name as parameter-variable. otherwise you just selecting plainText as record.

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE ProcName
#trendId as nvarchar(max),
#startDate as datetime,
#endDate as datetime
AS
BEGIN
 declare #stt varchar(200) = 'select deviceTimestamp,' + #trendId + ' '+'as reading from TableName where deviceTimestamp >= '+#startDate+'and deviceTimestamp < '+#endDate+' order by deviceTimestamp desc'
 exec ( #stt)
END   (I get the error : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.)

Comment: Thanks @Halil İbrahim this helped